# How to use an array in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

How do I make arrays in PL / SQL?

I have a string that I want to split on spaces and then loop through them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your array like this:

```
 "your array" apex_application_global.vc_arr2;

  "your array" :=  APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE("your string",' ');

  FOR i IN 1.. "your array".COUNT   LOOP

  "Your string" := "Your string"|| "your array"(i);

    END LOOP;
```

and there you have it

Answer (score 0):

And this is the ultimate and universal solution without using any packages, just oracle SQL. See a full featured solution (including a pipelining function) over here: http://www.armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/20-string-tokenizer-with-oracle-pl-sql

```
declare
  cursor c_tokenizer(ci_string in varchar2, ci_delimiter in varchar2) is
    SELECT regexp_substr(str, '[^' || ci_delimiter || ']+', 1, LEVEL) AS splitted_element,
           LEVEL AS element_no
      FROM (SELECT rownum AS id, ci_string str FROM dual)
    CONNECT BY instr(str, ci_delimiter, 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
           AND id = PRIOR id
           AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT null;

  l_string    varchar2(100) := 'Hello World, I like PL/SQL';
  l_delimiter varchar2(1) := ' ';
begin
  -- extract each word of the string above (delimited by blank)
  for c1 in c_tokenizer(l_string, l_delimiter) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c1.splitted_element);
  end loop;
end;
```

The Result is:

```
Hello
World,
I
like
PL/SQL
```